# What is a good way to package gtk python applications for windows xp?

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I'm trying to package a python 3.4 application that uses Gtk bindings for windows xp 32bit.

I installed windows xp sp3 32bit onto a virtual machine and installed the required dependencies, after fixing some linux specific issues I got it to run fine on windows xp.

However, I ran into a roadblock when trying to make it easier to distribute.

So far I've tried both cx_freeze and PyInstaller but both produce executables that fail with an error stating "ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available".
(Although PyInstaller does recommend me to install the package "gobject-introspection" for my platform, but I'm not sure where to find it)

I'm not very familiar with how these things usually work on windows.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a better recommended way to package this kind of thing?